# Network notification after installing kde-nm-connection-editor

Tags: network-manager, kde, notification

I have installed `plasma-nm` on my Ubuntu 14.04. Beside `nm-applet`'s notifications `plasma-nm` also started generating notification about available networks and `wlan0` association with selected networks.

[image]

For this reason I uninstalled plasma-nm. But these notifications didn't gone. So I removed kde-runtime and related dependencies from my system too. But These notification are still here and this is too annoying.

Any help on how to stop these notifications with out affecting other ones. Or alternatively which package/software is generating these notifications so that I can uninstall/disable it.

Comment: use `sudo apt-get purge plasma-nm` to remove `plasma-nm` completely.

Comment: @g_p it says `Package 'plasma-nm' is not installed, so not removed`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are dependencies which are not removed. If you have not any private information to hide in your installed applications (i.e you do not mind revealing what applications you have installed), please give me your package list so that i could try and find out which application you have to remove. To do that, open terminal and type

```
ls /var/cache/apt/archives > apt.log
```

This would generate the list of packages installed into the file apt.log. Then if you could paste it or upload it here or on the g+ community, I can verify it with the standard package list to find out which application is installed and needs to be removed.